# Definition of the conditional pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was wondering how the definition of the conditional pdf came about where,

$$f_{(X,Y)}(x|y) = \frac{f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$

I'm trying to understand this by thinking of the conditional CDF of $x$ given $y\in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$ then taking the derivative and the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ but I end up with the following which seems somewhat close?

$$\frac{d}{dx}[P(X\leq x | Y \in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)] = \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{P(X\leq x  \cap  Y \in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon))}{P(Y \in (y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon))}] = \frac{d}{dx}[\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_{(X,Y)(m,n) \,dn\,dm}}{\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_Y(n) \, dn}] = \frac{\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_{(X,Y)(x,n) \,dn}}{\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_Y(n) \, dn}$$

Then
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_{(X,Y)(x,n) \,dn}}{\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_Y(n) \, dn} = \frac{f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}?$$

This feels like it might be right? But I'm not quite sure if this is the right way to think about it or if the final line is even true and then how to show that it is true.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

> This feels like it might be right? But I'm not quite sure if this is the right way to think about it or if the final line is even true and then how to show that it is true.

Yes, that's basically it.   The final line can be shown using L'Hôpital's rule.

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_{X,Y}(x,n) \,\mathrm dn}{\displaystyle\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_Y(n) \, \mathrm dn}
& = \displaystyle\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\frac{\mathrm d\;}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\displaystyle\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_{X,Y}(x,n) \,\mathrm dn}{\frac{\mathrm d\;}{\mathrm d\epsilon}\displaystyle\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon}f_Y(n) \, \mathrm dn}
\\[1ex]
 & = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can this be shown without L'hopitals rule?